# Toasty, Burnt, Brûlée!

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

It turns out that my toaster is a tad broken. It lost WiFi (You know, it's one of those newfangled smart toasters), and its been going bonkers! Since it no longer works, I've been having to hack into my breakfast's source code and run `Plate.bread.toastAs(3);` every morning. Will you help?

My toaster takes one input: the amount of time you want to toast your bread. This is written as `min:sec`, such as `5:45` or `0:40` (Up to `59:59`). It then returns a specific value for different levels of toastiness:

```
0:00-0:30 = Bread
0:31-1:00 = Warm Bread
1:01-2:00 = Toasty
2:01-3:30 = Burnt
3:31 and up = Brûlée (or Brulee)
```

But here's the catch: my toaster has a broken keyboard! Your code can't contain any semicolons or...colons. This might be harder than the toaster repairman said it would be...

Here are some test cases, so you can...test your cases?

```
0:00 = Bread
5:50 = Brulee or Brûlée
2:00 = Toasty
ChicknMcNuggets = Anything
-1:00 = Anything
0:60 = Anything
1 = Anything
60:00 = Anything
1:00:00 = Anything
```

- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are prohibited
- [All Acceptable Forms of Input/Output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) are accepted
- My Toaster's new code cannot contain a semicolon (;) or colon (:)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer (in each language) wins!

Comment: Is the time at most `59:59`?

Comment: Oh, yes. Forgot to mention that!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `3:31 and up: Brulee`?

Comment: Where are all the golfing languages where colons wouldn't be used anyway?

Comment: So how to test the cases?

Comment: I have't realized until now why there aren't any Python submissions...

Comment: Can we take in input with a leading zero so that all inputs are 5 characters long?

Comment: @Quintec Hmm...no, it should work with`11:05` or  `1:05`. Sorry.

Comment: I meant like 01:05 and 11:05 instead of 1:05- just to clarify, that’s a no, right

Comment: @Quintec Yes, since it would make the code much shorter and pose a disadvantage to those which have already been submitted (Not to mention the fact that it would no longer be a big deal that there can be no colons).

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms "I have't realized until now why there aren't any Python submissions...". Why? :-)

Comment: @ElPedro Colons

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms. I know and that's why I put the smile on the end of my comment. It took me a while to work out how to avoid colons. For me that was what was the most interesting part about what what a good challenge anyway :)

Comment: Is the input suggested in [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/175152/toasty-burnt-br%C3%BBl%C3%A9e/175550?noredirect=1#comment422805_175550) acceptable? The input is literally `6:00` but that is evaluated by R to the vector `[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>124</s>  <s>118</s> 116

```python
t=eval(input().replace("\x3A","."))
print["Bread","Warm Bread","Toasty","Burnt","Brulee"][sum([t>3.3,t>2,t>1,t>.3])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY6xisMwDIZ3P4XRZEMJSUyHGhpoobfeUrghl8GkggbSxMjyXfL0OffcDuLT9/OD5Fe@z1O99fMNgzxKANj4iD9uVMPkIytdEPrR9ajgezEn2EEBWgtPw8QtnAndLWVfjh7yLdfZBV7Tco408ZMUR0To2hAfquXGFGbHTZ2mSlOYTndbOiwE02qFlL/3YUR5pYhW4oK9@v9OC1x69Cwvnx8Xopms9C6EDUpbliASzAtVQpXDhKfV2epsJjdNbu4Pdn@APw)

-6 with thanks to @tsh and also thanks for tho TIO test cases.

-2 with a couple of cool tips from @BlackOwlKai

Throws a `ValueError` for invalid inputs that cannot be converted to a float. For numbers less than 0 it returns "Bread" because it is still bread. Guess if we are really strict on ensuring that the input is a valid time it could be done but for me the interesting bit was how to avoid the `:` in Python.

Comment: [118 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY6xisMwDIZ3P4XRZEMISUzgamiHQm@9pdAhZDCujgTSxMgK1zx9zq3vhp9Pn/hBChsPy9zsfrljlEcJADsfv6fFsRrnsLLSJWGYnEflB1Lthy6gBK1FoHHmDs6E7g4F3Bw95L9cFxd5S8N5pZlfpHVChL6L60N1fDKlKfjUpNQppel1v6fTQjBtVkj5M4wTyiutaCU@0av3f1rg02Ngefn6vBAtZGVwMe5Q2aoCkWD@UCfUeZnwsiZbk83kpsnN9mDbA/wC)

Comment: @tsh Thanks for the neat trick and thanks also for the TIO tests.

Comment: -1 byte by replacing `float` by `eval`

Comment: Thanks @BlackOwlKai. Hadn't seen that. Will update tomorrow with appropriate credits ☺

Comment: -1 byte because `chr(58)` can be shortened to `"\x3A"`

Comment: Thanks @BlackOwlKai. Back on the laptop now so posted your tips. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL, <strike>409</strike> <strike>379</strike> <strike>328</strike> 318 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @i varchar(9)DECLARE @a time='0'+CHAR(58)+@i DECLARE @ int=DATEPART(N,@a),@s int=DATEPART(S,@a)SELECT CASE WHEN @<1AND @s<31THEN'Bread'WHEN @<1OR @=1AND @s=0THEN'Warm Bread'WHEN @<2OR @=2AND @s=0THEN'Toasty'WHEN @<3OR @<4AND @s<31THEN'Burnt'ELSE'Brulee'END WHERE LEN(RIGHT(@i,LEN(@i)-CHARINDEX(CHAR(58),@i)))=2
```

*-30 bytes: removed* `AS` *keywords, combined* `DECLARE` *statements (thanks to [BradC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/175152/toasty-burnt-br%C3%BBl%C3%A9e/175555?noredirect=1#comment422923_175555))*
*-51 bytes: changed declarations/where clause to take advantage of SQL's datetime functionality*
*-10 bytes: changed* `MINUTE` *to* `N` *and* `SECOND` *to* `S` (thanks to [BradC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/175152/toasty-burnt-br%C3%BBl%C3%A9e#comment422956_175555))

Did you know that SQL can't natively split strings in any decent capacity? Don't let `STRING_SPLIT` fool you; it doesn't work for this. Or at least, I'm not smart enough to figure it out.

Different from BradC's [table-based T-SQL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175614/83280).

Ungolfed:

```sql
-- Input variable
DECLARE @i varchar(9)

-- Time declarations (passes in as form "00:mm:ss")
-- CHAR(58) maps to ':'
DECLARE @a time = '0' + CHAR(58) + @i

-- Integer declarations
DECLARE @ int = DATEPART(N, @a),    -- minutes
        @s int = DATEPART(S, @a)    -- seconds

SELECT CASE
            WHEN @ < 1 AND @x < 31              -- 0:00 - 0:30
                THEN 'Bread'
            WHEN @ < 1 OR @ = 1 AND @x = 0      -- 0:31 - 1:00
                THEN 'Warm Bread'
            WHEN @ < 2 OR @ = 2 AND @x = 0      -- 1:01 - 2:00
                THEN 'Toasty'
            WHEN @ < 3 OR @ < 4 AND @x < 31     -- 2:01 - 3:30
                THEN 'Burnt'
            ELSE 'Brulee'                       -- 3:31 - 59:59
       END

-- Setting input as a time means that you only have to check if the seconds input is two characters, all other checks accounted for
WHERE LEN(RIGHT(@i, LEN(@i) - CHARINDEX(CHAR(58), @i))) = 2
```

Comment: You could do something like `SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@i,CHAR(58))`, although I'm wondering if a `TRY_CAST(@i AS TIME)` might cut some corners.

Comment: Interesting language for golfing!

Comment: @BradC I tried doing `STRING_SPLIT` like that, but it doesn't exactly work as you'd think - it actually returns both values from each side simultaneously, and you can't do any checks on the data (at least that I could figure out). As for using `TRY_CAST`, it looks like it would require having "00:" appended to the front. I might be able to work further with that.

Comment: Yeah, `STRING_SPLIT` returns them as separate rows. Even without changing those parts, you can still save a ton of bytes by keeping only your very first `DECLARE` and changing the rest to commas. Also drop `AS` and just do `DECLARE @i varchar(99),@a varchar(9)=...`

Comment: Yeah, good call. Since `@a` and `@b` both require `@i` though, I have to declare that separately. Can still save quite a few bytes there though.

Comment: Nice improvements! Save a few more by using `n` for `MINUTE` and `s` for `SECOND` in your `DATEPART()` functions: [DATEPART reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I knew there was a smaller way to write those. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 148 bytes

a lambda from `String` to `String`

```java
t->{float n=new Float(t.replace("\72","."))\u003breturn n>3.3?"Brulee"\u003an>2?"Burnt"\u003an>1?"Toasty"\u003an>.3?"Warm Bread"\u003a"Bread"\u003b}
```

`\u003b` and `\u003a` are source-level Unicode escape sequences for `;` and `:` respectively.

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##TVDBasJAED3HrxgGhATikipSTGsED956stBD9bDGjazdbMLurCVIvj3daJTCwMy8NzPMe2d@4ZPz8aer3UHJHHLFrYUPLjVcR8EAWuLk06WSRyg9FW7JSH363gM3Jxv1k8HZH2KOpGKF0znJSrPNULzfx2O45wwKWHY0ya6FqjiBXmrxC5u@DokZUSueixB3r1OMkWEU7VySzA5GkDMadDZjsxWujVNC4I3iOpt6xLP0BF5W@FlxS80T6be@uClhbQQ/DjD@aw5tFwRvXkpRGRgkgvchhf6/p@QrJmmSYAw4T@e3PH30i3S@wPbuR7BtLImSVY5Y7VdJPWxj/n7pteLYpjC2flPqGArG61o1odRRFPVftCMfbfcH)

### Ungolfed

```java
t -> {
    float n = new Float(t.replace("\72",".")) \u003b
    return
        n > 3.3 ? "Brulee" \u003a
            n > 2 ? "Burnt" \u003a
            n > 1 ? "Toasty" \u003a
            n > .3 ? "Warm Bread" \u003a
            "Bread"
    \u003b
}
```

### Acknowledgments

- -24 bytes thanks to [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%c3%a9goire)

Comment: `.replaceAll` can be `.replace` and `Integer.parseInt` can be `new Integer`, or `new Short` even, to save 10 bytes: [Try it online **162 bytes**](https://tio.run/##NVDLisIwFF3Xr7gEhAZq6GNE7PgAF7OblQOzUBexpk6cNC3JjYNIv70TrYXAuSf3de658CufXE6/XeOOShZQKG4tfHKp4T4KXp8WOXq41vIElU@FWzRSn3cH4OZs6aMyuPhBzKFUrHS6QFlr9vEKFn15BD2uoIRlh5PVXWoEvdTiD7Y/tcEQmRGN4oUIyX6WkogQSvcujrOjEeiMJhsj@Cn65qaCPvyqucVbtPFJjDbGKSEIs42SGPp2utOLLFnHzxlcL5I4WScDST1JB5L5sqwnb4d@ZdsFwbs/rKwNvA4G70oOT72DAXcS53FMIiDTfPrEdODzfDonbe9OsL1ZFBWrHbLGt6IaTGR@fsW93LHNYWx9p9QRlIw3jbqFUlNKHyrakX9t9w8).

Comment: [148 bytes](https://tio.run/##TVDBasJAED3HrxgGhATikipSTGsED956stBD9bDGjazdbMLurCVIvj3daJTCwMy8NzPMe2d@4ZPz8aer3UHJHHLFrYUPLjVcR8EAWuLk06WSRyg9FW7JSH363gM3Jxv1k8HZH2KOpGKF0znJSrPNULzfx2O45wwKWHY0ya6FqjiBXmrxC5u@DokZUSueixB3r1OMkWEU7VySzA5GkDMadDZjsxWujVNC4I3iOpt6xLP0BF5W@FlxS80T6be@uClhbQQ/DjD@aw5tFwRvXkpRGRgkgvchhf6/p@QrJmmSYAw4T@e3PH30i3S@wPbuR7BtLImSVY5Y7VdJPWxj/n7pteLYpjC2flPqGArG61o1odRRFPVftCMfbfcH) by changing the split to a simple ternary operator and using a `float` instead of an int to spare on the "hundreds" bytes.

Comment: Nice. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 100 bytes

```javascript
a=>'Bread,Warm Bread,Toasty,Burnt,Brulee'.split`,`[((t=a.replace(/\D/,'.'))>3.3)+(t>2)+(t>1)+(t>.3)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY69DoIwFIV3n4KwtI21/DQMYGAgPoKJg5rQQDFooU1bTHh6RByly8nNd77cnCd7M1PrTtmDUV3DdS@HF5/m1su9meUFKDVnDb4w3Xu/8yyZsRMuRz1YXOpRcA6IUaKzFa6uENqcEc2VYDWHwe0UYEAAQgUlFO2hLeI1ozUXdJ9rORgpOBHyAVvoh1kY@ggdd3@cuni0xSPHn4Vv@rHDjx0@deyhjj1JmiXpt5g/)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 91 bytes

```javascript
a=>[,b='Bread','Warm '+b,o='Toasty',o,u='Burnt',u,u][new Date([70,a])/-~18e5+1|0]||'Brulee'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BC4IwGIbv/YrhZYqzNkVKYx2inxB0EA9LP6OwLeZWBNJfX3bOXZ/34eG9iacYGn19mESqFlyHOHKC7ypy5nivQbSY4JPQd4TjM1EcH5UYzBsTRewkWC0NJpbYupLwQgdhIKzWlIg6WiUftoE8ZiOtx3Fq2R4Au0bJQfWw7NUl7MKAlpQGUbRd/PHMx9kcZ57OxGf91OOnHj/z/Mk8f/KizIvf4L4)

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, <s>143 155</s> 145 bytes

```
SELECT TOP 1b FROM i,
(VALUES(31,'Bread'),(61,'Warm Bread'),(121,'Toasty'),(211,'Burnt'),(1E4,'Brulee'))t(a,b)
WHERE a>DATEDIFF(s,0,'0'+CHAR(58)+v)
```

Line breaks are for readability only. Different method than Meerkat's [variable-based SQL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175555/70172).

Input is taken via pre-existing table **i** with varchar field **v**, [per our IO standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341). That input table is cross-joined to an in-memory table **t** with our cutoff values (in seconds) and the desired labels.

The magic happens in the `WHERE` clause: `DATEDIFF` calculates the difference in seconds between midnight and our input (with an extra `0:` attached to the front), then returns the lowest matching label (via the `TOP 1`).

Invalid inputs either return an unpredictable value or throw an error:
 `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

The question was a little vague, but if needed I can avoid these errors (and return nothing) by adding the following `LIKE` pattern to the `WHERE` clause, bringing the total bytes to **<s>238 211</s> 201**:

```
AND RIGHT('0'+v,5)LIKE'[0-5][0-9]'+CHAR(58)+'[0-5][0-9]'
```

**EDIT**: My original shorter submission was failing for inputs over `24:00`, since I was treating it as `hh:mm`. Had to add the `'0'+CHAR(58)+` prefix, which added 12 bytes.

**EDIT 2**: Shaved 27 bytes from the `LIKE` in my alternate version

**EDIT 3**: Removed `ORDER BY` from both versions, as it proved unnecessary in testing. (SQL doesn't *guarantee* sort order will be maintained without an explicit `ORDER BY`, but it seemed to work fine for me in this specific case.)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 96 bytes

```php
<?=[Bread,"Warm Bread",$t=Toasty,$t,$u=Burnt,$u,$u,Brulee][min(7,2*$argn+substr($argn,-2)/30)]?>
```

requires PHP 5.5 or later. Run as pipe with `-nF` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f29115a7aaa3e30a7a9952696de8ad464ea8c70f).

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>43</s> 42 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
þ30тx330)ć‹O„©Ãº™D#θ‚R.•liSÕô6>Āµ·•6ôÀ«™sè
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AVYAqf9vc2FiaWX//8O@MzDRgngzMzApxIfigLlP4oCewqnDg8K64oSiRCPOuOKAmlIu4oCibGlTw5XDtDY@xIDCtcK34oCiNsO0w4DCq@KEonPDqP//MToxNQ) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3l/8P7jA0uNlUYGxtoHml/1LDT/1HDvEMrDzcf2vWoZZGL8rkdjxpmBek9aliUkxl8eOrhLWZ2RxoObT20HShidnjL4YZDq4Hqig@v@K/z38DKwIDLwMrQCEgYg1jGhlyGIDEgAWIBJYxAXCMQ1wjENYYQQMXGIMUmIK4pkAAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
þ                # Leave only the digits of the (implicit) input
                 #  i.e. "1:15" → 115
 30              # Push 30
   т             # Push 100
    x            # Pop and push 100 and 100 doubled (200)
     330         # Push 330
        )        # Wrap the stack into a list: [inputDigits,30,100,200,330]
         ć       # Pop and push the head and rest of array as separated items to the stack
          ‹      # Check for each if its smaller than the head (1=truthy, 0=falsey)
                 #  i.e. [30,100,200,330] and 115 → [1,1,0,0]
           O     # Take the sum of this
                 #  i.e. [1,1,0,0] → 2
„©Ãº™            # Push string "warm bread"
     D#          # Duplicate it, and split it by spaces: ["warm","bread"]
       θ         # And only leave the last element: "bread"
        ‚R       # Pair them into a list, and reverse that list: ["bread","warm bread"]
.•liSÕô6>Āµ·•    # Push string "bruleetoastyburnt"
             6ô  # Split into parts of size 6: ["brulee","toasty","burnt"]
               À # Rotate it once towards the left: ["toasty","burnt", "brulee"]
«                # Merge both lists together:
                 #  ["bread","warm bread","toasty","burnt","brulee"]
 ™               # Titlecase each word: ["Bread","Warm Bread","Toasty","Burnt","Brulee"]
  s              # Swap so the number is at the top of the stack again
   è             # Index it into the list (and output implicitly)
                 #  i.e. 2 → "Toasty"
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `„©Ãº™` is `"warm bread"` and `.•liSÕô6>Āµ·•` is `"bruleetoastyburnt"`.

`þ30тx330)ć` can alternatively be `30тx)DOªsþ` for the same byte-count: [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AVYAqf9vc2FiaWX//zMw0YJ4KURPwqpzw77igLlP4oCewqnDg8K64oSiRCPOuOKAmlIu4oCibGlTw5XDtDY@xIDCtcK34oCiNsO0w4DCq@KEonPDqP//MToxNQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript(ES6+), 180 bytes

Node.js(180 bytes)

```
let f=(s,i=s.split("\u{3a}"),j=i[0]*60+1*i[1],k="Bread",l=assert(new RegExp("^(.|[0-5].)\u{3a}[0-5].$").test(s)))=>eval("(j<31)?k\u{3a}(j<61)?'Warm '+k\u{3a}(j<121)?'Toasty'\u{3a}(j<211)?'Burnt'\u{3a}'Brulee'")
```

Browser(188 bytes):

```
let f=(s,i=s.split("\u{3a}"),j=i[0]*60+1*i[1],k="Bread",l=console.assert(new RegExp("^(.|[0-5].)\u{3a}[0-5].$").test(s)))=>eval("(j<31)?k\u{3a}(j<61)?'Warm '+k\u{3a}(j<121)?'Toasty'\u{3a}(j<211)?'Burnt'\u{3a}'Brulee'")
```

Gotta use those unicode escape sequences :-) just a big chain of ternary operators, with variables defined by default parameters. Also a one-liner, so no semicolon-hungry js

Comment: I used a regex to enforce the 59:59 & no negatives rule :-)

Comment: OH WAIT I forgot i added :

Comment: actually done :-)

Comment: You don't need a regex to enforce the 59:59 and no negatives...they can result in anything, be it an error, nothing, or `Brulee`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>86 79</s> 67 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to nwellnhof! -12 bytes by porting [tsh's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175180/76162)*

```perl6
{<<Bread'Warm Bread'Toasty Burnt Brulee>>[sum S/\D/./X>.3,1,2,3.3]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv9rGxqkoNTFFPTyxKFcBwgzJTywuqVRwKi3KKwEKleakptrZRReX5ioE68e46OvpR9jpGesY6hjpGOsZx9b@L06sVEjTUDKwMjBQ0rTmgnONULnGqFwTUySuIapeINcQhYui1whVsRGqYmNUWWNUvUAusmJTVFlTSytTSyD/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 97 bytes

```
.+(..)
$*1#$1$*
+`1#
#60$*
#1{211,}
Brulee
#1{121,}
Burnt
#1{61,}
Toasty
#1{31,}
Warm #
#1*
Bread
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT1tDT0@TS0XLUFnFUEWLSzvBUJlL2cwAyFQ2rDYyNNSp5XIqKs1JTQXxDY3A/NKivBIQ1wzEC8lPLC6pBHGNQdzwxKJcBaARhlpAfamJKf//G1gZGHCZWpkacBkBWQA) Link includes test cases. Explantion:

```
.+(..)
$*1#$1$*
```

Convert the minutes and seconds to unary.

```
+`1#
#60$*
```

Multiply the minutes by 60 and add to the seconds.

```
#1{211,}
Brulee
#1{121,}
Burnt
#1{61,}
Toasty
```

Decode the seconds into the toastiness.

```
#1{31,}
Warm #
```

Decode Warm Bread by noting that `#` (for 0:00) decodes to `Bread`.

```
#1*
Bread
```

If we don't have a toastiness yet then the bread is still cold.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 130 bytes

```c
f(a){if(*strchr(a,58)=48,a=atoi(a),a=(int*[]){"Bread","Warm Bread","Toasty","Burnt","Brulee"}[(a>30)+(a>1e3)+(a>2e3)+(a>3030)]){}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZDBioMwEIbP@hRpoJCoC1EbaFPcQ59hYQ@uh8GabWCrJYmHInl2d7JdT98/8w//DNO/fff9umoGfDGaZc7b/mYZFPLIm8OxgAb8ZNBFxczos7bjC73YAa60oJ9g72QrPiZw/oniMtvRR9r5ZxhoaBm814LniHKo/1j9sxZoYGIIK4aTO5iR8SVN@htYkvnBedd2zUKFEgITpZIR1asqlSgjhColslbVKc6clIwUqsauCOc00ZONtxPTiPMr03Q71CbP47LkYdHVjO4dUWTvvkZabGOFZviS6/xgW4dzjpEhDesv)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 48 bytes

```
`BÎ%
W‡m BÎ%
To†ty
B¨›
BrÔ‡`·g[30LLÑ,330]è<Ur58d
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YELOJQpXh20gQs4lClRvhnR5CkKomwpCctSHYLdnWzMwTDIwMCwzMzBd6DxVcjU4ZA==&input=WyIwOjAwIiwKIjU6MDAiLAoiMjowMCJdCi1SbQ==)

Saved 5 bytes by actually reading the [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142629/71434)...

Explanation:

```
`BÎ%...BrÔ‡`·                       Compressed array of possible outputs
             g                      Get the one at the index given by...
                         è          The number of items...
              [30LLÑ,330]           From the list [30,100,200,330]...
                          <Ur58d    Which are less than the input without ":"
```

An [extra byte](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YN+EubBybSDnsCUphnR5ab9ym2lictSHYHFpIGdbRtFMTNEsMzMwXeg8VXI1OGQ=&input=WyIwOjAwIiwKIjU6MDAiLAoiMjowMCJdCi1SbQo=) could be saved by outputting in all lower case.

Comment: [46 if lower case allowed](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YN+EubBybSDnsCUphnR5ab9ym2lictSHYHFpIGdbRtFMTNEsMzMwXeg8VXInOg==&input=WyIwOjAwIiwKIjU6MDAiLAoiMjowMCJdCi1SbQo=)

Comment: [47 if not](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YELOJQpXh20gQs4lClRvhnR5CkKomwpCctSHYLdnW0bRTEzRLDMzMF3oPFVyJzo=&input=WyIwOjAwIiwKIjU6MDAiLAoiMjowMCJdCi1SbQ==)

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz both of those contain a colon, which isn't allowed by the challenge. `LÑ` saves a byte though, and I didn't think about whether all lowercase is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Snap! 4.2](https://snap.berkeley.edu/), <strike>257</strike> 251 bytes

Minified the text version some more.

I haven't found any answers in Snap!, a visual programming language similar to Scratch, so I'll use scratchblocks2 syntax, pretending that Snap! exclusive blocks are valid in scratchblocks2.

[**Try it online!**](https://snap.berkeley.edu/snapsource/snap.html#present:Username=wockykitaki&ProjectName=Toasty%2C%20Burnt%2C%20Br%C3%BBl%C3%A9e!) (click the button with the two arrows to see the code)

```
when gf clicked
ask[]and wait
set[l v]to(split(answer)by(unicode(58)as letter
set [t v]to(((item(1 v)of(l))*(60))+(item(2 v)of(l
if<(t)<[31
say[Bread
else
if<(t)<[61
say[Warm Bread
else
if<(t)<[121
say[Toasty
else
if<(t)<[211
say[Burnt
else
say[Brulee
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>127</s> 122 bytes

```r
function(t)cut((x=eval(parse(t=t)))[1]*60+tail(x,1),30*c(0:2,4,7,Inf),c("Bread","Warm Bread","Toasty","Burnt","Brulee"),T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcexCsIwEIDhVyk33dUTUpUKxS7d3AsO4nDEBAoxlfQi9emjDk7/96fiq9O2@BytTnNEJZsVce3dSwI@JS0OtVciuja3ujUblSngyg3x3tQWTbfjAx/5HD2xRRiSkzswXCQ9qv@Msyz6/mLIKeqvKQfngHik4hHazhig8gE)

Returns a `factor` with the appropriate level.

-5 bytes thanks to JayCe.

Comment: Would this work? https://tio.run/##NYi9CoMwEIBfRTLd2StcFDKUTm7dhQ7FIcQEBBvhvAw@faxDp@9Hamqe95pKDrpsGRRDUdCPnVrHN/XLCkoWKQBTz@SYbMfUWaZXTtc2g0Q/GzJvL9/mH@Pmdz1@MhTJelHKGqNBGrEmcA9mrCc

Comment: @JayCe IDK, the input is "any acceptable format" but then everything takes the string...I'll ask in the comments.

Comment: @JayCe I'm not sure what you mean. As far as I can see, it takes the time as an input to a function which is an acceptable input IMO

Comment: And you can also do `30*c(0,1,2,4,7,Inf)`

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms the input isn't a time, it's an array, `:` is the sequence operator.

Comment: @Giuseppe Hmm, I'd say that's a no.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>43</s> <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```
fØD~~ḌH“Ð2dʠ‘<Sị“¡Ḳḋ\ḞvṾƤSİƓƥeF½ÞØ+®°»Ỵ¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AV0Aov9qZWxsef//ZsOYRH5@4biMSOG4nuKAnMOHMWPGpeKAmDxT4buL4oCcwqHhuLLhuItc4bieduG5vsakU8SwxpPGpWVGwr3DnsOYK8KuwrDCu@G7tMKk////MTM6Mzc)

#### Explanation (old)

`“¡Ḳḋ\ḞvṾƤSİƓƥeF½ÞØ+®°»` is the compressed string `Warm Bread\nToasty\nBurnt\nBrulee\nBread`, found by the [compression optimizer](https://tio.run/##jVRLbhtHEF1zTlGxFtNjjQiSgh2EMheRkYW8jREtaMJozjTJpme6B91NUqRhwwdJrpFNdj6KL6K8ag4/kTaBCKGmuj6vXn2abVhYc/04c7ampaqqLem6sS5QYUv1sZFzlVOpi6CtkW77eAG98UGa0CWhHopq5fVaZYky5cdKGRrRgC6plg8CX2KT0cw62pA2Z0G6lTXzjC7IWDJKlRRsjKpL5c7N/IJxTFUhV16Rna61Xflqm5MOqaf4qlySXNCdKZySsFGzmS60MsWWNhqFrQJXU6lamaDNnCQFpxUJYPJhQV7XupIuS54lHdHn9ZB0RK9zWnMByqxq5WRQ4ql59iV5Uh39/wjRHBGSopLe01tbN055LyrtQzZMOqWaUbGQThaoVuxyKljb0dByzPSD@fDw8@z73ylrOxaJf3kFSVWwSPH3ZgRD/Eu/niysK0WRXV0PoqFX8cFJDQr/kNVK/eacdaJAJ1@Q9mgSyERvGqdNkNNK0a@/v727Q/8cKK20UTO0sfsiQ5gdA3j9cndp249ryD3IToWVM7RL9iWdGOCaNjmCGVU3YRurCx6eB82@2s142J/QaMRFDTFSI2j6w8kNtbYBAizLgrv3rKEI0A7kG3pNXPPTgYTvfU6@gLcAnF7GPvvJRcjoISKGrt/IpsC4iQwERRA59bM9yvuIZO80pGeUblpKTRqNwOo5jEjgDABQEo9ocUNLhjNgKEAWQfQjMFjEr94NZmzE2cb3k6SlnCuFJgPzulUNWDZBnEhoAc9i7w@NWp5//Gc6Dsr@81bOrdjFrhXt7GKlRzSeQLNZaEzLbh8Boxtbs65tKXZ0Rf2cBq96fAney084Htr4RmM/QAfFg/SODxJ2faqXCiytFU15zXEs1sp5NpPV3DpMZ80ZTvm7smlwksTxiI2LSXZCnv749ufn3pfv/6Rd7Gctg0jT7tJqI04hxsPhVX@SwWtfpW2CrmUlfHCx2LLhInsTeklXX5lWfuD@8cJzc500cyUOL3TVz@MvOsN7rDHNx3XvnlacnzAmfUwVHGHGUWPY5SksqKsBN3a6QXC@Me0NzvYZOsFt98IxGXtEOT/lPdtDfrpcHtIO97Kmn0ZYhoihg4OvmnA20G2CBpeLpRPDnGrMqpbqH9/@OnLNdOT8dgSBCULy3iSqkfST2o64ksd4ccTR7tADi@aKXtbF1S9FlmWP99LVdMufyXsrPW7GLVCE5NatKqWS@PIv).

```
fØD                               Filter out the non-digits (i.e. colon) from input
   ~~                             Use binary NOT twice to convert to digit list
     Ḍ                          
      HḞ                        Halve and floor. Now we have "01:45" -> 72.
        “Ç1cƥ‘                    The array [14,49,99,164]
              <                   Vectorized less than
               S                  Sum
fØD~~ḌHḞ“Ç1cƥ‘<S                How many threshold times is input less than?
                                           (0 -> Bread, 4 -> Brulee.)
                ị               Index (note 0ị gives the last list item) into
                       ¤        the new dyadic link given by
                 “...»            The long string, decoded and
                      Ỵ           split by newlines.
```

Inspired by Kamil Drakari's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175217/39328).

-2 bytes using snippet `~~Ḍ` from Dennis.

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 118 bytes

```
\>`tttt`,kw,kw,kw,ki
\uqn.3X)?\ . 1C)?\.2C)?\'Ŋ)?\"Brulee"
\D"daerB"L" mraW"/
$L"ytsaoT"L?9"tnruB"L?aL?3 F/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/GLqGEiYWxhIkbiIWAOEEnuxyGMrliSgvz9IwjNO1jFPQUDJ2BtJ4RiFQ/2gUklZyKSnNSU5W4YlyUUhJTi5yUfJQUcosSw5X0uVR8lCpLihPzQ5R87C2VSvKKSoGy9ok@9sYKbvr//xtZGVkCAA)

Utilizes some unprinting ASCII characters (STX, EOT, SOH, STX, VT, SOH, STX, DC2, SOH, and STX in that order) on the first line, which is reading in a sequence of bytes in the order that they're going to be needed on the stack. 3 divide (`'t'/2` equals `:`) and reflective-write operations are then performed. This puts 3 `:` (duplicate) commands where there are currently `.` (NOP) in order to non-destructively compare the input with the time thresholds. A fourth `:` is left on the stack before reading input.

Time is read in as a string, then split on `:`, and concatenated back into a string. As values above `59:59` do not have any specification on output, values like `1:00:00` will have undefined (but deterministic) output. This string is then converted to a number and compared against 30, 100, 200, and 330 (the byte value of `Ŋ`). `"Bread"` (line 3, executing RTL) is used twice, both for `Bread` and `Warm Bread` results, saving at least 5 bytes.

Saves 1 byte by not having a classic terminator command (`;`) by using `F`izzle on the last line instead. This convinces the parser that the program is guaranteed to terminate without causing it to do so immediately (and, more importantly, not touching the stack). Valid inputs will leave the stack empty so that when it loops around and touches a `w` the IP is terminated for performing an illegal action.

Comment: After reading the name of this language, I for some reason have the image of a wizard chanting ASCII code points stuck in my head.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms \*GRIN* https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/272860530505547776/536721740437520404/clank.gif

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, <s>115</s> 101 bytes

*-6 from tsh*

```
d=>[b="Bread","Warm "+b,a="Toasty",a,c="Burnt",c,c][~~(parseInt(d)*1.999+d.slice(-2)/30.1)]||"Brulee"
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 171 bytes

```js
(x,y=Math.ceil(x.split(/\D/).reduce((a,b)=>(+a)*60+(+b))/30))=>["Bread","Bread","Warm Bread","Toasty","Toasty","Burnt","Burnt","Burnt","Brulee","Brulee","Brulee"][y>8?8:y]
```

Run some test cases with this Stack Snippet:

```js
var f=(x,y=Math.ceil(x.split(/\D/).reduce((a,b)=>(+a)*60+(+b))/30))=>["Bread","Bread","Warm Bread","Toasty","Toasty","Burnt","Burnt","Burnt","Brulee","Brulee","Brulee"][y>8?8:y]

var result = document.getElementById("result");
["0:00", "0:30", "0:31", "1:00", "1:01", "2:00", "2:01", "2:30", "2:31", "3:00", "3:01", "3:30", "3:31", "4:00", "4:01", "4:30", "4:31", "5:00", "6:00"].forEach(x => result.innerHTML += `${x}: ${f(x)}\n`);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: @JoKing Whoops, I missed a few possibilities while trying to save bytes. Working on a fix.

Answer (score 0):

### F#, 177 bytes

```
let t i=
 let s=i.ToString().Split(char 58)
 let m=int s.[0]*60+int s.[1]
 if m<31 then"Bread"elif m<61 then"Warm Bread"elif m<121 then"Toasty"elif m<211 then"Burnt"else"Brulee"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZJda4MwFIbv@ysOgYJuU6KjMlzbi41d9GJjUGEXrYxgo4ZpdPHYUeh/d9G2VpuLkPc57/kISVxZUaF402QcAUEsJtCeqoWwg2KNSsjEMO11mQk0opQpmD2ZJ0u@EFIb7Q0N7zx6fxZOOAERQz5/dABTLsmL4mxHeNZB7wy/mMphFHHccygoWIWHC3adS5laSdS04rpinXFOms38TaI6fBa69TKcdDMxIYGpZA/6Hnptur1dxPUthzxfNfUpHeqZPxtp9yb@moroR75HH3WScKyGIcu58VLfG@lRY@@2c5vdoo6E3X5cwpr/2jkrwYhrCShyvpJljWAt@8QePsCVqUN/7vTV1fM/gWkvjvCtawJZyT3LxI6Yw/4CuToNYAyaYftCXAWamG1uqT8JxhLItNqiv8VpRQYDD91dbdr8Aw)

Thanks to Jo King for straightening out my, umm, needlessly literal interpretation of the challenge...

F# is fairly okay for functions without semi-colons or colons. The only real issue was that I couldn't do `i.Split` directly without a type annotation - F# would not have been able to deduce the type of `i` based on the method call. That would have required defining the type directly in the function, like `let t (i:string)=` which would have been against the rules.

But I could easily get by it by `i.ToString()`, which then allowed me to call `Split` on it. Then `char 58` is a colon character, and after that it's straight-forward.

Comment: But that's what the requirements specification said! :P